# Server fails to start with "apiKey value must be defined!"

Tags: node.js, json, npm, parse-platform, mailgun

I am installing server using bootstrap script on local mac. Server didn't start with error "apiKey value must be defined!". I removed complete emaiAdapter section from config.json but kept getting same error.

So i tried to install in another folder where it worked once. I added emailAdapter section and it failed. I removed section and tried starting again but it keeps failing withs are error.

I tried installing in different folder but no success. Lastly tried to start with default config.json created by bootstrap script but still failed.

**Steps to reproduce**

Install using bootsrap.sh
Add emailAdapter section in config.json
run npm start

**Environment**

tried 4.2.0, 4.4.0

**Server**

Parse Server version: 4.2.0 and 4.4.0
Operating system: macOS 11.0.1
Local or remote host (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, Heroku, Digital Ocean, etc): local
Database

System (MongoDB or Postgres): mongoDB
Database version: 4.2.3 community edition
Local or remote host (MongoDB Atlas, mLab, AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, etc): local

Error dump

```
> appname@ start /Users/ashishn/Documents/Developer/parse-server-local
> parse-server config.json

Configuration loaded from /Users/ashishn/Documents/Developer/parse-server-local/config.json
/Users/ashishn/Documents/Developer/parse-server-local/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/mailgun.js:16
      throw new Error('apiKey value must be defined!')
      ^

Error: apiKey value must be defined!
    at new Mailgun (/Users/ashishn/Documents/Developer/parse-server-local/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/mailgun.js:16:13)
    at create (/Users/ashishn/Documents/Developer/parse-server-local/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/mailgun.js:234:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ashishn/Documents/Developer/parse-server-local/cloud/main.js:28:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at new ParseServer (/Users/ashishn/Documents/Developer/parse-server-local/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:140:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appname@ start: `parse-server config.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the appname@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

config.json generated by bootstrap.sh without mailgun parameters.

```
{
  "appId": "62PQSaonSEg8WT5Gqpc7uQT4nkzNhsMzGz7XP592",
  "masterKey": "GWWdE90ymp2A7JsQEyx83NOI1VXlf1Jhx9q019v8",
  "appName": "lendable",
  "cloud": "./cloud/main.js",
  "databaseURI": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/parse"
}
```

config.json with email adapter parameters

```
{
  "appId": "myAppId",
  "masterKey": "masterkey",
  "cloud": "./cloud/main",
  "databaseURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/dev",
  "auth": {
    "facebook": {
        "appIds": "121233222"
    },
    "apple": {
        "client_id": bundleid 
    }
  },
  "verifyUserEmails": true,
  "emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration": 7200, 
  "preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail": true, 
  "publicServerURL": "http://192.168.1.10:1337/parse",
  "appName": "my app",
  "emailAdapter": {
    "module": "@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter",
    "options": {
      "fromAddress": "hello@xyz.com",
      "domain": "mail.myapp.com",
      "apiKey": "key-asdasdadsasdasd"
    }
  },
  "passwordPolicy": {
    "validatorPattern": "/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/", 
    "validationError": "Password must have at least 8 characters, contain at least 1 digit, 1 upper case and 1 lower case character.",
    "doNotAllowUsername": true, 
    "maxPasswordAge": 90, 
    "maxPasswordHistory": 5, 
    "resetTokenValidityDuration": 86400
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code where you use mailgun?

Comment: As I can see in the package description there should be apiKey indicated before using mailgun: `var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});`

Comment: @Anatoly This error is at server start and not when using mailgun in my code. I have used config.json with and without emailAdapter options. I have posted both versions.

Comment: @Anatoly i completely missed that line in the error stack. Thanks for pointing that out. I had to change that in my main.js that has cloud code.